# Why do I get packet loss when using GKMatchSendDataReliable?

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center, gamekit

I have a multiplayer iOS game, and I am sending data using `GKMatchSendDataReliable`. However, occasionally, the data packet is lost.  I've checked on the sending end and I am not getting an error.  I'm just not receiving it on the receiving in.  It is intermittent, and I have NSLogs right at the beginning of my receive method, so I always know when I get a message.

Is `GKMatchSendDataReliable` 100% reliable?  It seems like a waste to have to set up my own reliable data sending routines.

It seems that this only happens when one device is on Verizon's LTE network. I havn't tried any other cellular network. When using `Wi-Fi` only, not necessarily the same wi-fi, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too.  It appears that while `GKMatchSendDataReliable` is oodles more reliable than `GKMatchSendDataUnreliable` (which loses about 2% of packets in my tests), `GKMatchSendDataReliable` seems to occassionally lose *the first packet* I send (immediately after connecting).

Answer (score 0):

My users also complain that some data may be accidentally lost during the game. I wrote a [test app](https://github.com/rabovik/GKMatchPacketLostExample) and figured out that `GKMatchSendDataReliable` is not really reliable. On weak internet connection (e.g. EDGE) some packets are regularly lost without any error from the Game Center API.

So the only option is to add an extra transport layer for truly reliable delivery.

I wrote a simple lib for this purpose: [RoUTP](https://github.com/rabovik/RoUTP). It saves all sent messages until acknowledgement for each received, resends lost and buffers received messages in case of broken sequence.
In my tests combination "RoUTP + GKMatchSendDataUnreliable" works even beter than "RoUTP + GKMatchSendDataReliable" (and of course better than pure GKMatchSendDataReliable which is not really reliable).

Comment: Hey Yan, does your library support more than 2 players?

Comment: Hi! It was not a goal because I did not need it. However you may create several ROUSession instances (one for each connected player) and transmit data independently using these sessions. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Apple stated that this was a bug and fixed in iOS7

Comment: I am using iOS7 on all my test devices and I am still seeing this bug.